# MVC adding items to sessions and displaying in view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm working on a ASP.NET web shop but I'm stuck on a particular part. I'm trying to create a session whenever a user (not logged in) adds a CD or a DVD to their shopping cart. That way they can go to their cart (/shopping_cart) and see all of the products they have added.

However, I can't make it work. Whenever I click on 'add product' nothing really happens.

Here's my code:

ProductsController:

```
// POST: Producten/Details/9
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {
        Product p = db.Producten.Find(id);
        if (p != null)
        {
            Models.Winkelkar kar;

            if(Session["kar"] == null)
            {
                kar = new Models.Winkelkar();
            }else
            {
                kar = (Models.Winkelkar)Session["winkelkar"];
            }
            kar.AddProduct(p);

            Session["winkelkar"] = kar;
            //var products = Session["kar"] as List<Product>;

        }
        return View();
    }
```

My Models.Winkelkar looks like this:

```
 public partial class Winkelkar
{
    private List<Product> _List = new List<Product>();

    public List<Product> GetList()
    {
        // geeft een lijst van pbjecten terug
        return _List;
    }

    public void AddProduct(Product p)
    {
        _List.Add(p);
    }


}
```

And my view form looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post>
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.ID" />
    <input type="submit" name="toevoegen" value="Toevoegen" />
</form>
```

Now I'm trying to display the session on the same page, I'll move it to /shopping_cart once I know it works, but I'm trying to display it like this:

```
@Session["winkelkar"]
```

I've looked through many other solutions here, but nothing really seems to work.

**EDIT**

As pointed out below, I didn't have an action in my form. I changed it to:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Producten")" method="POST">
    ...
</form>
```

Getting one step closer.

Comment: Your form lacks an action. You have to HTTP Post your data to an action method. I suggest you start looking at some basic ASP.NET MVC Tutorials until you've got the basics down. And why did you tag this as PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the name "winkelkar" as your session key everywhere, expect on this line:

```
if(Session["kar"] == null)
```

That means you will never find your object, and always recreate a new one.

For this reason, you should avoid using a string literal for session keys, and declare a constant instead.

And as mason pointed out in his comment, your form has an empty `action` attribute. You should have something like that:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Products")" method="post">
    ....
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It didn't really solve the issue though sadly :(

Comment: @Albert.tomasiak see my edit, it may solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I've looked some things up after Fran pointed it out, but that just gives me 404 errors.. My controller is named ProductenController so my action looks like
"@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ProductenController")" I even tried adding an Id to it with ... , new { id = @Mode.ID } but that didn't work either.. Thanks for the help though, my guess is that I've made a silly mistake somewhere :)

Comment: The second parameter of `Url.Action` should be `"Producten"`, not `"ProductenController"`. It is the MVC name of your controller, which is the class name without "Controller" at the end (in ASP.net MVC, every time you must refer to a controller, you should give this name, without "Controller").

Comment: Thanks, that was actually really helpful! One more question though, I placed @Session["winkelkar"] on the details page just to check what gets added, but it returns "ASPExamen.Models.Winkelkar".

Do you have an idea whether I'm adding the wrong thing in my function, or am I just displaying it wrong?